# Better to abstract out detail or use a setter?

Tags: java

In terms of best practices, suppose I have this code:

```
public class ClassObject {
    private int someNumber;

    public void setSomeNumber(int x){
      this.someNumber = x;
    }

    public int getSomeNumber(int x){
      return this.someNumber;
    }

    //Should I even use this?
    public void decreaseSomeNumber(){
       --this.someNumber;
    }

}


public void doSomeStuff(ClassObject instance){
   // do some things
   instance.decreaseSomeNumber(); //A
   instance.setSomeNumber(instance.getSomeNumber() - 1); //B
}
```

I am wondering if either lines `A` or `B` are code smells. I think `decreaseSomeNumber()` is likely a redundant/useless function since I can just do `instance.setSomeNumber(instance.getSomeNumber() - 1);` everwhere.

On the other hand, it seems slightly more verbose doing `instance.setSomeNumber(instance.getSomeNumber() - 1)`. What is the cleanest and good code design between `A` and `B`?

Comment: Do you use the getter / setter elsewhere?

Comment: BTW, your getter has a redundant parameter x.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a multithreaded environment, having (A) a `decreaseSomeNumber` method is worth it, however, you should make it threadsafe. Otherwise (B) two parallel threads might try to decrease the value at the same time, resulting in just a single decrease operation if they overlap.

That being said, it's typically hard work to *really* make code threadsafe, and in simple cases, occasional glitches might not matter. However, *occasional* is the keyword here: If you ever run into these, reproducing the problem will be horribly hard.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of best practises you must **avoid** when is possible the form

```
public void decreaseSomeNumber(){
   --this.someNumber;
}
```

and prefer the standard getters and setters.

But in some cases you need to decrease the value of a variable,
if this thing is **occasional** is good to use getters and setters

```
instance.setSomeNumber(instance.getSomeNumber() - 1);
```

instead in the case you need decreasing the a variable **repeatedly** (ex. A withdraw in a bank account) using only one method is not bad, but it must be defined like

```
public void decreaseSomeNumber(int many){
   this.someNumber -= many; 
}
```

in this way you are making a code more reusable, and this is good

P.S. the B way is more simple to syncronize in multi-threading enviroments

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

I would recommend changing this class as follows:

```
public class ClassObject {

private final int someNumber;

public ClassObject(int someNumber) {
    this.someNumber = someNumber;
}

public int getSomeNumber() {
    return someNumber;
}

public ClassObject decreaseSomeNumber() {
    return new ClassObject(someNumber - 1);
}

public void doSomeStuff(ClassObject instance) {

      //New ClassObject with new someNumber(instance's someNumber is decreased one unit)
      ClassObject decreasedNumberClassObject =  instance.decreaseSomeNumber();
}

}
```

I mean, if you wanna make a change in the Class properties(decrease, increase, multiply,...), it must return you, **new Object(from the same Class)**, with the new property.

This code completely follows **OOP paradigms**. It is **thread-safe**, **immutable** and software(code) **maintenance** will be very high with the help of this approach.

Comment: Immutable objects probably are not a good idea when doing frequent math, for the same reason using Integer objects to do math is not a good idea.  Usually, it will result in a lot of objects being created and garbage collected in a short period of time.

Comment: @VGR Yes you're right, I just wanna show what is the best way to have a clean and standard code. Certainly, the context of software(Math, Business, ...) must be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on more specific details, but I would be probably in favour of decreaseSomething.

With the getter and setter, you implicitly assume that:

1. The user of the API implements some (albeit trivial) computation.
2. The computation is performed at the time of the request.
3. The caller handles to concurrency-related issues on their own.

The (1) is rather a philosophical problem, although it might lead to errors caused by inadvertence, like calling get and set on two different objects.

The (2) can be a practical problem. Maybe you want to use the object from multiple threads. And maybe you don't need the number often, but you need to change it often. I believe that one could come up with some optimizations based on LongAdder or LongAccumulator or AtomicInt, which can optimize some highly concurrent places. With decreaseSomething, you can do it inside the class implementation. With getters and setters, you would need to somehow replace all occurences of `x.setSomething(x.getSomething() + 1)` by something else. That does not look like a proper encapsulation…

The (3) depends on your objective. Some people just make thread-unsafe code and claim it is programmer's responsibility to handle locks where needed, which can be OK. Sometimes, there might be a demand for thread-safe code. With getter and setter, you would need to use some locking scheme every time you access the data (which also makes (1) a less philosophical issue). Sometimes, it can be awful. Sometimes, it can be OK, because the caller wants to lock something more than just this one object.

As mentioned on the start of the post, I don't say I would prefer it every time. Maybe there are some cases when I would not go this way.